# Outer function being called before xmlhttprequest being done

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, xmlhttprequest

room.onPlayerChat is an outer event i have no control on it, When i try to use it i need to process something on message and checking player role through xmlhttprequest and wait for response then send message to room chat but it doesn't wait for it(xmlhttprequest) to return the player's role and send the normal message (normal player role), how to hang that outer event (room.onPlayerChat) and its needed to handle any room chat source.

```
const makeRequest = (method, url, data = {}) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve({
      status: xhr.status,
      response: xhr.responseText
    });
    xhr.onerror = () => resolve({
      status: xhr.status,
      response: xhr.responseText
    });
    if (method != 'GET') xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    data != {} ? xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data)) : xhr.send();
  })
}

room.onPlayerChat = async function (player,message) {
  let request = await makeRequest("GET", 'URL/TO/CHECK/PLAYER/ADMIN/ROLE' + player.name);
    
    if (request.response == "YES")
    {
            room.sendmessage("ADMIN" + player.name + message);
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `xhr.open()` should be inside the promise.

Comment: It returns the result, but its late after the room.onPlayerChat being finished and it send the message 2 times (one as normal player and one as admin player message), i dont want the normal player chat message being sent at all if he is an admin player

Comment: I don't see how it can "not wait". The promise isn't resolved until the response is loaded.

Comment: `data != {}` is not the way to test if the `data` argument was supplied. Change the default value to `null` and test `data != null`

Comment: And nothing here will make it send the message 2 times.

Comment: Add some `console.log()` statements to see what's being run when.

Comment: I already did, and everything is being processed as it is and return the data needed as the code i posted, but i dont need to send the normal player chat message

Comment: Are you sure the API is returning something other than `YES`  in that case? I don't see any other reason why it would send them the message.

Comment: yeah, its being worked and send both normal message and message as admin, but i want to slow down so it can send only one message (Admin one).

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted would send two messages. Unless it's responding to its own chat, but that would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to discord.js @Barmar

Comment: I assumed this was a discord bot.

Comment: Well even if it was a discord bot it doesn't seem that they are using the discord.js module, they are using HTTP requests

Comment: No, its related to haxball if you know it